# Ubuntu GUI is lagging(shown in video)

Tags: gui

I've recently moved from Windows to Ubuntu, but the interface is lagging when I move windows or watch a video. Graphical drivers seem to be installed correctly.[this is a video with an example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jSW6Z-9aMJMk-QEFY6NVPjusxgrMdJJP/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) If you are running using VM, then try other flavors like Xubuntu or MATE.

Comment: @N0rbert, I have a laptop with an Intel i7-7700hq, Nvidia gtx 1050(mobile) and 8 gb of ram. I've installed Ubuntu on a ssd as my main operating system. So  I don't think the minimal requirements are the problem.I thought maybe the graphic drivers are the problem. I tried to install Intel graphic drivers  by using sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel and get "xserver-xorg-video-intel is already the newest version". What should I try next?:))

Comment: Probably `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` may help.